# Import Maven project into eclipse looping

Tags: eclipse, maven, import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOYvq.png)

import Maven project into eclipse remain 49% for last 3-4 hours.

Comment: Open the "Error Log" view and see if there are any plugin errors logged. Press Ctrl-3 and then type "Error Log".

Comment: Can this be reproduced with a current Eclipse instead of the pretty outdated Eclipse you have? If yes, what happens if you cancel importing? Please show your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I am using latest Eclipse, JDK11 and latest Maven but no error on Error.log file

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRKcE.png)

WinHttp.GetProxyForUrl for pac failed with error 'The handle is invalid.
' #6.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).